# How can I add values in the second column of a CSV file?

Tags: bash

I have a huge csv file in the format of:

ID number, dollar amount, date

I want to add all dollar amount values in the file

example record in the csv:

```
12345678, 600500.55, 2020-04-20
```

How can I get an output of the total dollar amount in the file?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your file :

```
12345678, 600500.55, 2020-04-20
12345679, 1213.70, 2020-05-20
12345680, 96767.55, 2020-06-20
```

This will do :

```
awk -F',' '{sum=sum+$2}END{print sum}' yourfile.csv
```

Output :

```
698482
```

If you want to be precise, then :

```
awk '{sum=sum+$2}END{printf("%.2f", sum)}' yourfile.csv
```